# Why is a rectangle not a neighborhood of its corners?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

I'm trying to puzzle out a statement given in [the Wikipedia article on topological neighborhoods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(topology)), which uses this definition:

> If $X$ is a topological space and $p$ is a point in $X$, a neighborhood of $p$ is a subset $V$ of $X$, which includes an open set $U$ containing $p$.

The picture used to illustrate the corner argument is this:

[image]

I guess I can understand that if $p$ pictured is a member of $V$'s boundary set, which is closed (by the definition of boundary sets?), then the rectangle $V$ does not include an open set $U$ containing $p$, but that's somehow unsatisfying. What if $V$ were actually equal to the whole space $X$? What if $V$ were closed and open at the same time?

More simply, why does the neighborhood of $p$ have to be a disk that extends both inside and outside of $V$?

I have essentially no experience in topology, I'm just doing this out of curiosity.

Comment: If the rectangle is the whole space, then the part of the open disk in the picture that is outside the rectangle is empty.

Comment: You're correct that if $V = X$ is the entire ambient space, then it is a neighborhood of its corners.  The example is assuming that the rectangle is being considered as a subset of the entire plane.

Comment: Glad to know my intuition works a little bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A neighbourhood of $p$ doesn't actually have to be a disk, but it does have to contain an open set containing $p$.  This means that it will actually contain some open disk centred at $p$, and no matter how small such a disk is, it will not lie completely inside the rectangle $V$.

This example is definitely assuming the ambient space is the *Euclidean metric space* (not just topological space) $\mathbb{R^2}$ (or at least a big enough piece of it to completely contain the picture!), in order for 'rectangle' to actually have a meaning.  In a general topological space, there is not necessarily such a thing as a rectangle.

You are right that if the ambient space $X$ was only part of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $p$ was on the edge of $X$, then it could be possible for a rectangle to be a neighbourhood of $p$.

Comment: I'll take a look at metric spaces then and try to put it together. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I had made a mistake in the first sentence.  A neighbourhood needn't be an open set.  I've fixed it now.
You don't really need anything about metric spaces, since the topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a metric space is the same as the usual topology (basic open sets are open balls).

Comment: "Note that due to the definition of the norm, the unit circle is always convex and centrally symmetric (therefore, for example, the unit ball may be a rectangle but cannot be a triangle)." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Properties). By analogy, do the symmetry and convexity requirement of distance functions give rise to the 'ball-like' shape of neighborhoods in metric spaces?

Comment: Where is that from?

Comment: Specifically, there is the sentence: "Note that due to the definition of the norm, the unit circle is always convex and centrally symmetric (therefore, for example, the unit ball may be a rectangle but cannot be a triangle)." If the norm is a distance function on a vector space like $\mathbb{R}^2$, this is intuitively satisfying to me, and fits with the image on the neighborhood article.

Comment: Ah, I see.  So I meant that in the example the space must be the _Euclidean_ metric space $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Sorry, I didn't think to specify that!  (Will fix it now.)  So in that space, the open balls are open disks.

Comment: In most pictures you will see neighbourhoods drawn as balls, but actually they needn't be.  They will, however (in Euclidean space), have a 'rounded' shape, since they are unions of balls.

Comment: @TaraB Neighborhoods, even open ones, need not be rounded.  An infinite union of open balls can have sharp corners.  For example, the open rectangle $(0,1) \times (0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: It doesn't really have sharp corners. =]  I know what you mean, though.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ and $V$ are the same rectangle, then this rectangle is in fact a neighborhood of its corners.  I think you're supposed to assume that the ambient space $X$ is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (even though it had to be cropped to a rectangle in the picture.)

Because $\mathbb{R}^2$ is connected, the only subsets that are both closed and open are $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ itself.

Comment: So the image is kind of an appeal to intuition based on the assumption that $X$ is part of $\mathbb{R
}^2$?

Comment: I suppose images are always appeals to intuition.  In any case we have to assume $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ to make sense of the word "rectangle" in the example.  No boundary of $X$ is drawn, so I'd assume $X$ is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$.